# Manipulate XML comments with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I need to read an XML file and comment or uncomment some elements to it based on some conditions.
The file starts off like this:

```
<elements>
    <!-- <element1 atribute="value"/> -->
    <!-- <element2 atribute="value"/> -->
    <!-- <element3 atribute="value"/> -->
    <!-- <element4 atribute="value"/> -->
    <!-- <element5 atribute="value"/> -->
</elements>
```

If I want to activate `element1`, `element3` and `element5`, the file should look like this:

```
<elements>
    <element1 atribute="value"/>
    <!-- <element2 atribute="value"/> -->
    <element3 atribute="value"/>
    <!-- <element4 atribute="value"/> -->
    <element5 atribute="value"/>
</elements>
```

In other words, I'm looking for a way to add or remove `<!--` `-->` tags from each XML line that meets the conditions.
Unfortunately, this behavior is needed, and cannot be changed.

Comment: Improved code and text formatting and added a little explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment is a special type of node. You cannot "toggle" from/to a commented/uncommented state. I see at least too possibilities here, both without JAXB only though :

### The DOM way :

1. Parse the XML file with a DOM parser of your choice (`with setIgnoringComments(false)`)
2. Get the raw data from each node (see [Comment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Comment.html).[getData()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/CharacterData.html#getData%28%29))
3. Create a new node from the string
4. Replace the "comment" node with your new node (see [Node.replaceChild](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#replaceChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29))

Don't hesitate to ask if you need a more detailed answer. You should easily find extensive documentation for each step.

### The XSLT way :

You could also use XSLT, as @Xavier pointed out in the comments. The issue here is that a pure match and replace will output the comment's content as unescaped text and won't recognize it as real XML data. You can use saxon to circumvent this I suppose, with something like that :

```
<xsl:template match="comment()[contains(., 'your conditional match')]">
    <xsl:variable name="comment" select="saxon:parse(.)" as="document-node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$comment"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I really wanted to use pure JAXB to achieve this. I don't really want to toggle, I would settle for adding such a comment because I know going in what needs to be commented and what needs to be set.

Answer (score 5):

I think reading commented and uncommented makes this problem complex. Simpler way would be adding attribute by which you can either activate tag or deactivate. No workaround would be required just you would require to mark it true or false.

For Example:

```
<elements>
    <!-- <element1 atribute="value"/> -->
    <!-- <element2 atribute="value"/> -->
    <!-- <element3 atribute="value"/> -->
    <!-- <element4 atribute="value"/> -->
    <!-- <element5 atribute="value"/> -->
</elements>
```

could be transformed into to.

```
<elements>
    <element1 atribute="value" isActive="false"/>
    <element2 atribute="value" isActive="false"/>
    <element3 atribute="value" isActive="false"/>
    <element4 atribute="value" isActive="false"/>
    <element5 atribute="value" isActive="false"/>
</elements>
```

Similarly, below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements>
    <element1 atribute="value"/>
    <!--<element2 atribute="value"/>-->
    <element3 atribute="value"/>
    <!--<element4 atribute="value"/>-->
    <element5 atribute="value"/>
</elements>
```

could be transformed into to.

```
<elements>
    <element1 atribute="value" isActive="true"/>
    <element2 atribute="value" isActive="false"/>
    <element3 atribute="value" isActive="true"/>
    <element4 atribute="value" isActive="false"/>
    <element5 atribute="value" isActive="true"/>
</elements>
```

This could be optimized way of solving this problem. Now, you might use JAXB and mark element active or inactive in stead of commenting and un-commenting.

If this doesn't makes your life easier there is always workaround using regex, xslt etc..

Comment: Read the question of OP properly, it is clearly mentioned that we cannot change the behavior, I quote "Unfortunately, this behavior is needed, and cannot be changed."

Comment: Nicolas is right. I have no control over the XML. I have to change values according to these ill conceived specifications

Answer (score 4):

For such need I would clearly suggest `XSLT` as it is somehow an `XML transformation` and `XSLT` has been created to transform `XML` content.

I would then use a **template** of a stylesheet that is meant to be used as a String format like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='2.0'>
  <xsl:template match='/'>
      <elements>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="elements/element1" mode="%s"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="elements/element2" mode="%s"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="elements/element3" mode="%s"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="elements/element4" mode="%s"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="elements/element5" mode="%s"/>
      </elements>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match='*' mode='normal'>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match='*' mode='comment'>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="."/>--<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see there are 2 modes:

1. if you choose `normal` it will simply copy the content of the node
2. if you choose `comment` it will comment its content

So in case we activate `element1`, `element3` and `element5`, the real content of our stylesheet will be `String.format(template, "normal", "comment", "normal", "comment", "normal")`

In the code snippet below, I use [jcabi-xml](http://xml.jcabi.com/example-xslt.html) as it is very easy to use but you are free to use another library if you wish, `XSLT` is a standard so it will still work.

```
XML first = new XMLDocument(
    "<elements>\n" +
        "    <element1 atribute=\"value\"/>\n" +
        "    <element2 atribute=\"value\"/>\n" +
        "    <element3 atribute=\"value\"/>\n" +
        "    <element4 atribute=\"value\"/>\n" +
        "    <element5 atribute=\"value\"/>\n" +
        "</elements>"
);
String template = "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='2.0'>\n" +
    "  <xsl:template match='/'>\n" +
    "      <elements>\n" +
    "          <xsl:apply-templates select=\"elements/element1\" mode=\"%s\"/>\n" +
    "          <xsl:apply-templates select=\"elements/element2\" mode=\"%s\"/>\n" +
    "          <xsl:apply-templates select=\"elements/element3\" mode=\"%s\"/>\n" +
    "          <xsl:apply-templates select=\"elements/element4\" mode=\"%s\"/>\n" +
    "          <xsl:apply-templates select=\"elements/element5\" mode=\"%s\"/>\n" +
    "      </elements>\n" +
    "  </xsl:template>\n" +
    "  <xsl:template match='*' mode='normal'>\n" +
    "      <xsl:copy-of select=\".\"/>\n" +
    "  </xsl:template>\n" +
    "  <xsl:template match='*' mode='comment'>\n" +
    "      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&lt;!--</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select=\".\"/>--<xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&gt;</xsl:text>\n" +
    "  </xsl:template>\n" +
    "</xsl:stylesheet>";
XML second = new XSLDocument(
    String.format(template, "normal", "comment", "normal", "comment", "normal")
).transform(first);
System.out.println(second.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements>
    <element1 atribute="value"/>
    <!--<element2 atribute="value"/>-->
    <element3 atribute="value"/>
    <!--<element4 atribute="value"/>-->
    <element5 atribute="value"/>
</elements>
```

**NB:** For the sake of readability, I formatted the output

Answer (score 3):

I do not think it is achievable using `JAXB` purely. Here is a way to achieve using `STAX API`. I used similar implementation where i needed to manipulate `XML comments`

```
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

    XMLEventReader reader =factory.createXMLEventReader(new FileReader("input.xml"));

    XMLEventWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventWriter(new FileWriter("out.xml"));


    String toggleMe = "element2";
    String regEx = "<!--(.*)-->";
    while(reader.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();

        if(event.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT) {
            if(event.toString().contains(toggleMe)) {
                 String xmlElement = event.toString().replaceAll(regEx, "$1");

                 XMLEventReader elementReader = factory.createFilteredReader(factory.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xmlElement)), new DocElementEventFilter());
                 while(elementReader.hasNext()) {
                     writer.add(elementReader.nextEvent());
                 }
            }else {
                writer.add(event);
            }
        } else {
            writer.add(event);
        }

    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
```

This is very specific to the example xml you have given and currently support toggle of one element. You can extend it to toggle multiple elements as well.

Above code also uses following Event Filter

```
class DocElementEventFilter implements EventFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(XMLEvent event) {

        return !(event.isStartDocument() || event.isEndDocument());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.